# Query with colon giving MySQL statement error

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple MySQL query

```
$name = 'Long's Jewelers';
```

The query is,

```
$query = "SELECT callDetails.* , clients.* FROM callDetails JOIN clients ON clients.id = callDetails.userId WHERE storeName LIKE '%".$name."%'";
```

When i run this query i get error at

```
Long's JewelersYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Jewelers%'' at line 1
```

What is wrong with this query? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you're SQL injecting yourself. The string contains a `'`, which makes your string (surrounded by `'`s) end prematurely. You should really use mysqli or pdo with real parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using PDO**

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT callDetails.* , clients.* FROM callDetails JOIN clients ON clients.id = callDetails.userId WHERE storeName LIKE :name");
$query->bindValue(':name',"%$name%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query>execute();
```

where $con is your connection

**Solution using mysqli**

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
```

**Mysql is deprecated** (if you are still using it)

```
mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

In case of mysql/mysqli escape the string before $query. It will help you avoid sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Write your variable like

```
$name = 'Long''s Jewelers';
```

and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$name = 'Long''s Jewelers';
```

you can also use :

```
'Long\'s Jewelers';
```

you could use `php` function `mysql_real_escape_string` :
then try :

```
$name = "Long's Jewelers";
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
```

see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) document.

Comment: actually the variable is coming from database. is there anyway i can encode it with php?